# How to add addtional parameters when submit with script?

Tags: javascript, submit, form-submit

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" name="get" />
    <input type="submit" name="add" />
</form>
```

A form with 2 submit button, when I click "get", it will send data with a get paremeter:

```
get=get
```

Now I want to submit the form by script:

```
form.submit();
```

No parameter is sent, then how can I add an addtional parameter like click a submit button?

```
form.submit('get'); or form.submit('get=get');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```js
form.get.click();

//or

form.add.click();

//instead of
//form.submit();
```